# Check if powers have the same unit digit

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

The task is to check whether $A={27}^{{27}^{27}}$ and $B=({27}^{27})^{27}$ end with the same last digit. So I'm looking for $x,y$ so that $x \equiv {27}^{{27}^{27}} \mod{10}$ and $y \equiv ({27}^{27})^{27} \mod{10}$.

I have reduced $A,B$ to $A=3^{{3}^{82}},B=3^{{3}^{7}}$. For B we can write $3^{{3}^{7}}=3^{{3}^{4 \cdot 1 +3}}$ and since $3^4 \equiv 1$, $B \equiv 3^3=27\equiv 7$ which is the last digit of B. However I struggle to do the same for $A$. Also is there an easier way without having to directly calculate the last digits?

Answer (score 2):

We want to see whether $A\equiv B \pmod {10}$ where $A=27^{27^{27}}$ and $B=(27^{27})^{27}=27^{27^2}$. Since $\varphi(10)=4$ and $\gcd(27,10)=1$, by [Euler's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) the above is equivalent to $27^{27} \equiv 27^2 \pmod{4}$. Now we can use the theorem again with $\varphi(4)=2$ and the statement turns into $27 \equiv 2 \pmod 2$
which clearly does not hold, hence the original statement does not hold, i.e. $A$ and $B$ do not have the same last digit.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, $$27\equiv 7 \mod10$$

This means $$27^n\equiv 7^n\mod10$$

We can also see that powers of $7$ mod $10$ would repeat every four:

$$7^1\equiv 7\mod10$$
$$7^2\equiv 49\equiv9\mod10$$
$$7^3\equiv 63\equiv3\mod10$$
$$7^4\equiv 21\equiv1\mod10$$
$$7^5\equiv 7\mod10$$

We can also see that powers of $3$ mod $10$ would repeat every four:

$$3^1\equiv 3\mod10$$
$$3^2\equiv 9\mod10$$
$$3^3\equiv 27\equiv7\mod10$$
$$3^4\equiv 21\equiv1\mod10$$
$$3^5\equiv 3\mod10$$

and so $$27^{4n+x}\equiv7^{4n+x}\equiv 7^x\mod10$$

We also have that the powers of $7$ mod $4$ would repeat every two:

$$7^1\equiv 7\equiv 3\mod 4$$
$$7^2\equiv 21\equiv 1\mod 4$$
$$7^3\equiv 7\equiv 3\mod 4$$

This means if $n$ is a positive integer,

$$7^{2n+1}\equiv 1\mod 4$$

When $n=1$ and $n=13$, we can end up having

$$7^{27}\equiv7^3\equiv1\mod 4$$

And thus

$$7^{7^{27}}\equiv 7^{7^3}\mod 10$$

This means that

$$27^{27^{27}}\equiv 7^{27^{27}}\equiv 7^{7^{27}}\equiv 7^{7^3}\equiv 7^3\equiv 3\mod 10$$
$$(27^{27})^{27}\equiv (7^{27})^{27}\equiv (7^3)^{27}\equiv 3^{27}\equiv 3^3\equiv 7\mod 10$$

Therefore, $x=3$ and $y=7$. Note that the exponents must be viewed as a whole for simplification.

Comment: You established that you can reduce the exponent mod 4, but in the final steps you seem to be reducing the exponent mod 10 instead, and also reducing the exponent of the exponent which has no justification.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis On the top, I wrote that 27^n is equivalent to 7^n (mod 10) (by the way, where did i mention mod 4? I cannot really see it)

Comment: "repeat every four" and $7^{4n+x}≡7^x$ establishes that you can reduce the exponent mod 4.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Silly me! I edited my answer. Could you please check if it's correct now? Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146685/discussion-between-cheese-cake-and-jaap-scherphuis).

Comment: It looks good now.

Answer (score 1):

$A \equiv B \pmod{10} \text{ iff } {7}^{{27}^{27}} \equiv  7^{27 \cdot 27} \pmod{10}$

Now since

$7^1 \equiv 7  \pmod{10}$
$7^2 \equiv 9  \pmod{10}$
$7^3 \equiv 3  \pmod{10}$
$7^4 \equiv 1  \pmod{10}$

we can write

$A \equiv B \pmod{10} \text{ iff } {{27}^{27}} \equiv  {27 \cdot 27} \pmod{4}$

But
$\; {{27}^{27}} \equiv  {{(-1)}^{27}} \equiv -1 \pmod{4}$
and
$\;  {27 \cdot 27} \equiv (-1)(-1) \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$

and so the numbers $A$ and $B$ have different unit digits.